# Why we need to use new keyword if hiding is intended, when we can directly create ClassA object and call printA method of classA

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Why we need to use new if hiding is intended, when we can directly create ClassA object and call printA method of classA

I'm confused why do we need this new keyword here when we have the option to directly create class object and call the required method:

```
                class Program
                    {
                        static void Main()
                        {
                            classA clsA = new ClassB();
                            clsA.printA();
                        }
                    }

                    public class classA
                    {
                        public classA()
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ClassA constructor");
                        }

                        public void printA()
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ClassA-PrintA Method");
                        }
                    }

                    class ClassB : classA
                    {
                        public ClassB()
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ClassB constructor");
                        }

                        public void printB()
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ClassB-PrintB Method");
                        }

                        public new void printA()
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Class B extending ClassA.PrintA Method");
                        }       
                  }
```

Difference between below code implementation when anyway we have to call PrintA method of class A in both the cases...

1) Using new keyword with the method in the both the base and derived class        ------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    class Program
                {
                    static void Main()
                    {
                        classA clsA = new classA();
                        clsA.printA();
                    }
                }

                public class classA
                {
                    public classA()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ClassA constructor");
                    }

                    public virtual void printA()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ClassA-PrintA Method");
                    }
                }

                class ClassB : classA
                {
                    public ClassB()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ClassB constructor");
                    }
                    public new void printA()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Class B extending ClassA.PrintA Method");
                    }
                }
```

2) Without using new keyword and no printA implementation in ClassB              ----------------------------------------------------------------
         class Program
                    {
                        static void Main()
                        {
                            classA clsA = new classA();
                            clsA.printA();
                        }
                    }

```
                public class classA
                {
                    public classA()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ClassA constructor");
                    }

                    public void printA()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ClassA-PrintA Method");
                    }
                }

                class ClassB : classA
                {
                    public ClassB()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ClassB constructor");
                    }
                }
```

what is the real time need of new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`new` keyword requirement is there to draw your attention to the fact that the method in the parent class will be hidden and not overridden.

Hiding isn't really one of the best practices when it comes to OOP, virtual methods are more common. IMHO the developers of the c# compiler decided that if the class declares a member with the signature that is equivalent to that of any other member's down the inheritance chain, and there is no `override` prefix - it might be a mistake, so the compiler asks whether hiding is intentional.

Comment: I don't think new keyword here hiding the parent class method instead when I run this code it gives me ClassA-PrintA Method

Comment: @BhuwanPandey You get a different result if your variable type is ClassB instead of ClassA, because the method is hidden and not overwritten. This may be unintuitive or unintentional behavior, therefore the compiler forces you to be explicit.

Comment: That's why the new keyword is required - to avoid confusions like the one you run into. You call printA() method on the variable of type classA, so regardless of the variable's contents, the compiler will bind the methods of type classA, *unless* you reference virtual methods, in which case it will perform vtable lookup and select the method based on actual object stored in the clsA variable and not its static type

Comment: Thank You Denis...If I took this correctly..you mean if I use 
            dynamic clsA = new ClassB(); instead of 
            classA clsA = new ClassB();  so that will force it to bind the PrintA to the ClassB?

Comment: If I understand your intentions correctly, you just need to declare `public virtual void printA()` in ClassA and `public override void printA()` in ClassB, then you don't need to worry about dynamics or new keywords - your original code will call method printA from ClassB

Answer (score 1):

You don't **need** the [new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) keyword unless you *wish* to hide the base class member, and then you do need the keyword as that is how the C# language is designed. The code would not compile without it.

Typically, you declare a function in your base class and not redefine in the derived class, or you define the base class function [virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) (can be overridden) or [abstract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) (must be overriden).

So: `ClassB` could be written without any `printA` function at all as it is already declared in the base class and is not `abstract`:

```
class ClassB : classA
{
    public ClassB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassB constructor");
    }

    public void printB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassB-PrintB Method");
    }
}
```

The above will compile and `printA` will be callable from `ClassB` but will use the implementation in `ClassA`.

Furthermore, consider this:

```
        classA clsA = new ClassB();
        clsA.printA();
        new ClassB().printA();
```

Output:

> ClassA constructor
>
> ClassB constructor
>
> ClassA-PrintA Method
>
> ClassA constructor
>
> ClassB constructor
>
> Class B extending ClassA.PrintA Method

Do you see that when you instantiate a `ClassB` but store it in a `ClassA` variable you get the output from the `ClassA` version of the function, whereas `new ClassB.printA()` returns the output from the `ClassB` version?

---

It sounds to me like you want to have ClassB.PrintA() output different from ClassA.PrintA(), but you want to be able to call ClassA.PrintA() from an instance of ClassB too. You can do it by declaring ClassA.PrintA() as virtual:

```
public class classA
{
    public virtual void printA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassA-PrintA Method");
    }
}
```

and overriding the function in ClassB:

```
class ClassB : classA
{
    public void printB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassB-PrintB Method");
    }

    public override void printA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Classb-PrintA Method");

        // Let's also call the ClassA version, just to show you how it works
        base.printA();
    }
}
```

And just to prove the point, we've called the ClassA version too using the [base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword.

```
void Main()
{
    new ClassB().printA();
}
```

Console output:

> Classb-PrintA Method
>
> ClassA-PrintA Method

Comment: Hi Stephen my point if I have printA in both A and B class and I want to use Class A print method...then why people go for new with the method name in the child class instead of directly calling the base class printA method.............

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer but maybe didn't do well enough at it: people generally don't do that. You would normally just define the method in classA, or you would define as virtual or abstract in classA if you want to allow or require derived classes to behave differently. You then call object.printA() and it *should not matter* which class the implementation is defined in. Try to think of these classes as black boxes where you don't even know what is inside (the logic is encapsulated, you just know the interface).

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes. I am going to add to my an answer a better implementation of what I think you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Bhuwan, I've added the approach I think you need to take. I see you've also been discussing the same with Denis. I hope that answers the question satisfactorily?

Comment: Hi Stiphen..Thank You for taking all the pain to clear my doubt ...Could you please check my updated question once.

Comment: Please read the hyperlinked articles in my answer for more details Bhuwan, and read both answers again if need be. You probably only ever need use 'new' to hide a base class member when you don't control the source code of the base class. Use 'virtual' and 'override' if you need different behaviour in the child class, or just declare the method in the base class _only_ if you want derived classes to behave in the same way as the base class. Don't forget to accept Denis' answer or mine if either answered your question best. Good luck.